# useradd --create-home not adding a home directory Rocky Linux 8 but does in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, rpm, useradd, rpm-spec

I have an RPM that runs a scriptlet to add a user and create a home directory.
I have used this before on CentOS 7, but now need this RPM to run it on Rocky Linux 8 so I've rebuilt the RPM (it's noarch but needed other changes), but run into this issue when installing the RPM on Rocky 8 when it comes to adding the user, that I did not come across on CentOS 7:

`useradd: cannot create directory /opt/system-installer`

The script does some checks adds a group if necessary but essentially runs the command:

`useradd --system --gid usergroup --home-dir /opt/app-user --shell /sbin/nologin app-user --create-home --comment "App Management User"`

If I run the command in the terminal there is no problem, but whenever I install the RPM the user home directory is not created and I run into issues with the user.
I have tried altering the scriptlet to make the directory before running the `useradd` command but because the directory is already there it doesn't copy over the .bash* files either.

I have also tried `adduser` as an alternative but have the same issue, it can't create the home directory.

What about running the command as part of an RPM scriptlet could be different to running the command via the commandline or a bash script (which I have also tried without issue")? All are run as `root`.

One thought I have as a temporary measure is to run a command to copy over the files from `/etc/skel` but that doesn't quite seem right to me.

Comment: "*but whenever I install the RPM the user home directory is not created*" what are the script(s) you are using for that? If you said it does work directly in terminal but in a shell script maybe you have a mistake in your script. So please provide what you have in your script(s).

Comment: It is when it is part of a %pre scriptlet in RPM spec that I get the issue, it is the exact command I shared above, copied and pasted. Running it in the terminal or in a shell script is fine, but part of the spec file as a scriptlet is when the issue arises. It does create the user but not the home directory for the user. It is a problem with where the code is not a mistake in the script.

Comment: And just to repeat/clarify this works as expected on CentOS 7 (so I reason it is not a mistake in script) it does not work correctly on Rocky 8, and to clarify the changes I mention in the question are not changes to the RPM spec that did not appear to be required, as it's noarch. The changes are to versions of things packaged in the RPM that get installed after this scriptlet with the command is run so have no affect.

Comment: I've never worked with scriptlet for rpm, so I'm not sure if there is a way to debug your script, for example redirect the logs to some files. Maybe the problem is related to permission issues (or maybe SELinux prevents the scriptlet from creating the home directory). I'll try to test a scriptlet in a rocky container.